# Numerical Solutions Using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am new to MATLAB and know a little of Calculus. Having whatever read on web I found that solving Differential / Integral / Sequences and Series problems in MATLAB we have to use symbolic package.

Below is one of the problems in Integration. Similarly we have Differential / Sequences and Series problems:

[image]

[image]

I always get stuck on how to solve these type of numerical analysis using MATLAB. Can anyone please provide some light on how to do Differentiation / Integration / Sequences and Series problems in MATLAB.

It would be a great help as many times I am stuck using these concepts which I feel learning is very crucial. A couple of examples would be best.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that I have a quite good view of what you want. I only need to ask one thing; The solution that you need, does that one use a symbolic expression to evaluate and return a numerical answer, or do you rather want a vector of numerical samples to evaluate?

Comment: Using symbolic expression is quiet easy - I need vector of numerical samples on how to solve these types cause I feel that one should know how to solve these problems - using symbolic expression just hides the steps to solve them

Comment: I agree on that. This is not the best of answers, so I decide to answer in a comment. As I started with matlab for a few years ago, I can tell you that then there was a larger offer of numeric intgral functions. It is a bit sad that most of them have been replaced by integral functions using function handles or symbols. The only method that I have found that is left is trapz, which uses the trapezoidal method. I guess that if you need something more sophisticated than that you have to do it the hardcore way. If anyone have a better answer I would be interested as well.

Comment: I'm a bit stumped on how a *numeric* solution to an indefinite integral should look. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @bdecaf you have a good point there, I did not even notice. I simply assumed that Prakash wanted to use a numerical solution to solve an integral, given two vectors of x and y samples. Does that make any sense to you Prakash? Please elaborate some more about what you want to do.

Comment: Is it that for solving Differentiation / Integration problems in MATLAB we need to work only with Symbolic Packages? What are the other type of methods one can use to solve these types of problems in MATLAB?

Comment: You still have not answered bdecaf's question which imo is valid here. However, if you want to solve a numerical problems given vectors of sampled data then trapz is the only method, which I know about, to do it. Otherwise you will have to use these methods using function handles or symbols like `int,quad,integral2,...`. However, it is not so hard to make a custom function which works better than trapz. Say for example simpsons method (unmodified), which is O(h^2).

Comment: Actually while studying DSP and Image Processing - there are a lot of Integrals and Differentiation to be solved - hence I just wanted to be doubly sure that which method one should use or learn - Symbolic or any other methodology.